# How to copy from excel rows to word paragraph

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, copy-paste

How to copy from excel rows to word paragraph.
ex data from excel

```
1.   robin   d123   e123
2.   morgan  f123   e456
```

paste to word become:

>   1.
>
> robin
>
> d123
>
> e123
>
> 2.
>
> morgan
>
> d123
>
> e456

Comment: The most easiest I would suggest is,, first use `TRANSPOSE` command in `Excel`,, *convert Row data into Columns* and finally `Copy` it to word,, you may record entire process as Macro also.

Comment: I have no problem with it (Excel 2013), copied rows in Excel correspond to pasted rows in Word (2013).

Comment: I would copy from Excel into a robust text editor like EditPad or Notepad++ and find/replace the delimiters between test with linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have values in your cells *with the new line mark at the end.*

(Excel allows multi-line entries in its cell - pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while entering a value means going to the next line in the cell.)

So try editing a cell (<kbd>F2</kbd>) and delete (<kbd>Back Space</kbd>) this newline character.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: @AlexM, if I thank as you, I didn't write an answer :-) See my comment just under the question.